# How to add more fields to this variable?

Tags: php

Hi I have this ajax code in a WP enviroment, it pulls and shows content from the post_content field.
the variable $raw_content , i want to "add" to it other fields, so they echo in the front end (like custom fields and post_title), how can I do that?

```
case 'load_more_content':
    $postid = $base->getPostVar('postid', 0, 'i');
    if($postid > 0){
        $raw_content = get_post_field('post_content', $postid);
        if(!is_wp_error($raw_content)){
            //filter apply for qTranslate and other
            $content = apply_filters('the_content', $raw_content); 
            self::ajaxResponseData($content);
        }

    }
    $error = __('Post Not Found', EG_TEXTDOMAIN);
break;
```

I have Been trying for hours to achieve without success to do this.

another approach tried was to create a aditional     case 'load_more_content': instance, but this didnt not work either. I need to show this fields in the front end, but seems so hard. thanks for your help.

Comment: I have tried multiple combinations, none of them did nothing but a white screen. I did not paste all the attempts i made because really, they are all white screens and i cant figure out which one is the "better" erroneous approach.

Comment: White screen usually means there's a error and you simply don't have error reporting turned on, I'd suggest you turn on error reporting and give your attempts another try, maybe one of them worked but failed because of a easily fixed mistake / error?